# FME Desktop 2019.2 Geodatabase_SDE writer copies Dataset parameter from reader when I said not to

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form

I'm using FME 2019.2, Geodatabase_SDE reader and writer with different connection files.

I have one database "Operations" with user1 and another database "Data_Sources" with user2. They both support geometric data used in ArcGIS. I try to read from Operations.user1.featureclass1, and write to Data_Sources.user2.featureclass2.

Operations.user1.featureclass1 is in a dataset "ops". I'm tryng to just write a standalone featureclass in Data_Sources, so i am leaving the Feature Dataset parameter as blank. However, seems that no matter what i try, the error keeps getting thrown that I can't do the operation because I'm not the database owner. And the log says it was trying to write Data_Sources.user2.featureclass2 to the Operations.Ops dataset.

The message is:

```
Geodatabase Writer: Creating feature class `User2.Featureclass2' in feature dataset 'Operations.User1.Ops'

An error occurred while attempting to create the feature class 'User2.Featureclass2'. The error number from ArcObjects is: '-2147220969'. The error message from ArcObjects is: {Must be the owner to perform this operation.}

A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
```

I am able to read from Data_Sources and create a new featureclass in the same Data_Sources gdb using Geodatabase_SDE reader and writer. 
Also, it seems to be ok when I use SDE30 legacy reader: I am able to create and write a featureclass in the other database, so this way I am able to achieve what I want. The issue is just when I read from the other database using Geodatabase_SDE. And unfortunately, the legacy reader isn't supported anymore, so I need to solve this using Geodatabase_SDE reader.

Why does this Geodatabase_SDE writer keep trying to write to a dataset (seems to be based on the source data) when I am trying to tell it not to?

Comment: This might help someone: https://knowledge.safe.com/answers/111494/view.html see proposed answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer did the trick](https://knowledge.safe.com/answers/111494/view.html)

Basically I needed to expose the geodb_feature_dataset using AttributeExposer and then use AttributeManager to set this attribute to null.